# Can't create Policy: 'no matches for kind "Policy"'

Tags: kubernetes, audit, policy

I am following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) on how to create a policy to audit actions in Kubernetes.

When I run the following YAML file:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF  
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1 # This is required.
kind: Policy
# Don't generate audit events for all requests in RequestReceived stage.
omitStages:
  - "RequestReceived"
rules:
  # Log pod changes at RequestResponse level
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
    - group: ""
      # Resource "pods" doesn't match requests to any subresource of pods,
      # which is consistent with the RBAC policy.
      resources: ["pods"]
EOF
```

I received the following error:

> error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Policy" in
>   version "audit.k8s.io/v1"

I tried to change the `apiVersion` to `audit.k8s.io/v1beta1` and also `v1` but it failed with the same error.

Notice the flag `--audit-policy-file` doesn't appear in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` but I don't think it is related because this is just about creating an object.

If you want to reproduce you can go to https://labs.play-with-k8s.com, create a cluster and try to create the policy.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same on Kubernetes 1.11 using:

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
```

Fixed by changing to:

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Answer (score 1):

The audit policy file is specified when launching the apiserver:

> You can pass a file with the policy to kube-apiserver using the --audit-policy-file flag.

Comment: when Im adding `--audit-policy-file='/policy.yaml'` OR `--audit-policy-file` OR `--audit-policy-file=/policy.yaml` the kube-apiserver crash all the time. Only after I am removing one of the line I mentioned it start to work normal again.

Comment: Make sure the policy file is visible to the apiserver process at the specified path

Comment: It is visible, I changed the location to be inside `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` and it still  crashes the API server. After I remove the line `--audit-policy-file='/etc/kubernetes/manifests/policy.yaml'` it returns to work again.

Comment: @E235 did you solve your issue?

Comment: @laimison no, but it was long time since I tried it. Maybe now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022.08:

For kubernetes v1.21 (or even lower version) and higher, the `kube-audit` used `Policy` API version is `apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1`,  old version `v1alpha1`, `v1beta1` are DEPRECATED.

Both following files

`k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/apis/audit/v1alpha1/types.go`
`k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/apis/audit/v1beta1/types.go`

said:

`DEPRECATED - This group version of Policy is deprecated by audit.k8s.io/v1/Policy`

You can NOT use `kube apply -f a-policy.yaml` to create a `Policy` object, the error message is `no matches for kind "Policy" in version "audit.k8s.io/v1"`.

The only way is to add such param `--audit-policy-file='/policy.yaml'` to `kube-apiserver` when it is started.

Namely, `kube-apiserver` does NOT support dynamicly watching a `Policy` object and enabling the `kube-audit`. Well, it is not in `kubernetes style`.

When your `policy.yaml` is not effectively parsed by `kube-apiserver` (e.g. wrong API version), which will crash. It is a bit complex to debug such a `policy.yam`. Read kubernetes document and source code, try again and again, until the `kube-apiserver` startsup successfuly with your given `policy-file`.